# jquery mobile how to highlight ui-state-highlight

Tags: jquery-mobile, highlight

Does jQuery mobile has anything for highlight? For example, highlight a table row.  Jquery ui has ui-state-highlight.

```
<table>
   <tr class="ui-state-highlight">
```

It should works with different themes and swatches.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
I'm also searching for that question. The only way I just now can think at this is using jQuery to find the selector:
 $("table tr.myTR").addClass('error');*/


----------


    <style>
    .error {
    background-color: #fbec88;
    }
    tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #e9e9e9;
    }
    </style>


 <div data-role="content">

        <table data-role="table" data-mode=""  id="myTable">

            <tbody>
            <tr class="myTR">
                <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Maria Anders</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Obere Str. 57</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Berlin</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>12209</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("table tr.myTR").addClass('error');
    })

</script>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue